# Hard to click links on touchscreen

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, touchscreen

This is my setup(sorry for the bad indetation):

```
<div class="container">
   <a href="somewhere">
    <div class="tall"></div>
   </a>
  <a href="somewhere else">
    <div class="small"></div>
  </a>
</div>
```

I also have some basic hover styles on the "container". My problem is that on mobile (im currently testing on iOS) the two links that wrap around the "tall" and "small" are hard to click. They trigger the hover style on the "container" but you have to hold your finger on them for a second(or even more) for the link to actually open. 
Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: Don't be sorry about the bad indentation just fix it, it's easier

Comment: make them bigger - if something is hard to click on because it is too small, make it bigger and easier clickable.

Comment: Don't use div inside a. It is not standard to use it. A block element should not be inside an inline element like <a ...>.

Comment: The size is not the problem, the "tall" div is around 200px tall and it's still hard to click. It's the same with <button> elements.

Comment: mobile browsers delay click by around 300ms to detect double-tap. Is this the issue you have ? You may be able to disable this function.. This also means that it will be harder to double-tab on your page though.

Comment: I'm not concerned for the double tap, how can I disable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the :hover selector on a link does that on touchscreen devices - i.e. it will show the hover effect for a second or two and then click the link. The best way to handle this would be to just detect device type and remove the :hover style altogether. You won't need it for a touchscreen anyways.

Read this: http://www.prowebdesign.ro/how-to-deal-with-hover-on-touch-screen-devices/